# How to sync with pending results in channel?

Tags: go, locking, synchronization

I have a worker pool which offers a sync interface to pull out results:

```
func (p *Pool) Get() *Result {
    for {
        select {
        // if there are results in channel return them
        case r := <-p.results:
            return r
        // else check if there is any work pending we must wait for
        // if not return nil to indicate that all work was done
        default:
            if p.active < 1 {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that Get will return the next worker result or `nil` if all work is done.

The problem with this implementation now is that I need to manually keep track of all active work with the `p.active` counter. This feels somehow wrong as theoretically the information sits already in the length of the `p.results` channel.

**What is an idiomatic approach to return nothing if a buffer is empty?**

Comment: Do you know before hand how many workers you will have?

Comment: @OneOfOne yes workers are fixed.

Comment: The problem is that the moment you request a result and you get nil, the result is already outdated. Such a design might be prone to race conditions.

Comment: How do you mean this @FUZxxl? Please explain further.

Comment: Really the atomic counter is the most efficient solution for this, anything else would be too complicated.

Comment: @bodokaiser Between the time your Get() function returns nil and the action you perform depending on that information, the last worker in your thread pool might have finished. You have to design your code in a way that this case does not matter.

Comment: @FUZxxl As the counter is increased with the added task I do not see any way how Get() could return nil except Add() or Put() would be called exactly in the same time as Get() executes the if clause?

Comment: @bodokaiser Ah, I didn't see the for loop. Please disregard my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no `len(chan)`, your approach is as good as it gets if you don't know the number of workers.

However you need some kind of synchronization for the counter, here's an extremely simple approach:

```
type Result struct {
    I int
}
type Pool struct {
    res chan *Result
    c   int32
}

func New() *Pool {
    return &Pool{
        res: make(chan *Result),
    }
}

func (p *Pool) Put(r *Result) {
    atomic.AddInt32(&p.c, 1)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(100+r.I%1000) * time.Microsecond)
    p.res <- r
}

func (p *Pool) Get() (r *Result) {
    for {
        select {
        case r = <-p.res:
            atomic.AddInt32(&p.c, -1)
            return
        default:
            if atomic.LoadInt32(&p.c) == 0 {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)
    p := New()
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        go p.Put(&Result{i})
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Microsecond)
    for {
        r := p.Get()
        if r == nil {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("r.I", r.I)
    }
}
```

//edit

For completeness sake, here's another example using [WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), but again this is an overkill since internally WG uses atomic counters anyway.

```
type Pool struct {
    res chan *Result
    wg  sync.WaitGroup
}

func New(n int) (p *Pool) {
    p = &Pool{
        res: make(chan *Result, n),
    }
    p.wg.Add(n)
    go func() {
        p.wg.Wait()
        close(p.res)
    }()
    return
}

func (p *Pool) Get() *Result {
    for {
        r, ok := <-p.res
        if !ok {
            return nil
        }
        p.wg.Done()
        return r

    }
}

//func Put is the same as above and the test code is the same.
```

Comment: In 99.9% of all cases what is not possible with this approach but good to know that you also can use wit groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `WaitGroup`, and a gorouotine that blocks on it, and changes some flag when it's done.

So say you have a waitGroup, and for each item you enqueue you call `wg.Add(1)` on it. Every time you receive on the channel, or every time a worker finishes, it can call `wg.Done()` to decrease its counter.

Then you have a goroutine that waits for evertyhing to finish, and just sets a flag:

```
 go func() {
     wg.Wait()
     p.done = true //do this thread safe of course
 }
```

And in your default case, you simply check the done flag

```
   default:
        if p.done {
            return nil
        }
```

See the docs on `WaitGroup` for more details. The example there is a bit similar to your case. http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait

Comment: I already tried to utilize a WaitGroup for this unfortunately some workers are faster then others so that they will block at a time.

Comment: It shouldn't affect anything. What did you try?

Comment: With WaitGroup you wait until a group of routines finished. This means I need to wait until all worker have finished what is not intended.

Comment: @bodokaiser no, you wait until a counter reaches 0, you can increment and decrement wherever you want.

Comment: Yes and when does the counter reach 0? When all worker are finished?

Comment: This would only work when it would wait on 1 but then you have a deadlock at some time.

Comment: @bodokaiser you decide when to call `wg.Done()` it can be called by any goroutine and not when one exits. you can call it in your Get method after receiving from the channel for example.

Comment: I tried this the problem is that you even you call wg.Done() once another routine/method can call wg.Add(1) and then wg.Wait() blocks again.

Comment: @bodokaiser so you start blocking on it after you've started all your tasks, there's no point in starting the wait beofre anyway.